# AJAX not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer-9

This is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("trazi_drzava");
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("trazi_grad").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gradovi.php?selected=" + x.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and I call it like this:

```
 <select name="td" id="trazi_drzava" onchange="loadXMLDoc()">
    <option value="">Država</option>
    <?php
    $sel_grad_arr=array();
    $sel_grad_arr[]="<select name='tg' id='grad0'>  
    <option value=''>Grad</option</select>";
    if($q=mysql_query("SELECT drzava_id,drzava FROM drzava")){
    while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        echo '<option value="'.$r['drzava_id'].'">'.$r['drzava'].'</option>';
       }
     }else echo mysql_error().__LINE__;
    ?>
    </select><select name="tg" id="trazi_grad">
      //code that ajax should load        
    </select>
```

It works fine with most browsers, but with Internet Explorer 9 it doesn't work at all. Anyone have any idea why?

UPDATE: I didn't manage to do this then. So I changed logic of working totaly. Thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: keyword is jQuery, or other Javascript framework... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Webarto Sorry I don't understand...

Comment: What is failing? Add debug statements. Is the function running at all? Is the HTTP request being made? You say it "works fine with any other browser", so it works in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: Adding 32KB of minified, compressed boilerplate is some people's answer to any problem.

Comment: in the function there is xmlhttp.open("GET","gradovi.php?selected="+x.value,true);
   xmlhttp.send(); It fill <select name="tg" id="trazi_grad"> with result from gradovi.php and it's working in every other browser than  Internet explorer 9

Comment: it worked in explorer 8, but the problem is that I need it to work in IE9

Comment: use <select name="td" id="trazi_drzava" onchange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)"> and use x = this.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but still, one with no actually correct answer....

The correct order of operations is:

1. Create your request object
2. `open` a connection
3. Set `onreadystatechange` listener
4. `send` request

You have steps 2 and 3 in the wrong order, which causes problems in certain browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a cache problem. Parameter test set as a timestamp value, something like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gradovi.php?selected="+x.value+"&t="+parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10)),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Regards!

Comment: thanks but that's not a problem. There is a problem with IE 9

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had a similar problem, which occurred only with IE9. My problem was the cache of IE9 and the instruction that solved. Either way, good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check how your request is sent to server. What does the double quotes look like? IE9, at least with jQuery, doesn't encode double quotes correctly according to this post:
[Why does this jQuery Ajax call fail ONLY in IE9 (Even works fine in IE8 and IE7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905911/why-does-this-jquery-ajax-call-fail-only-in-ie9-even-works-fine-in-ie8-and-ie7)

Comment: Nope! I try that too,but nothing happend! I hate IE!

Comment: @Marko This is a really long shot but maybe this helps: http://cggallant.blogspot.com/2011/03/xmlhttprequest-calls-when-in-ie-9.html quote: "the XMLHttpRequest object still returns an MSXML ActiveX object from the reponseXML property no matter which document compatibility mode IE 9 is using. The MSXML ActiveX XML object is not compatible with the DOMParser XML object and will result in a 'Type mismatch' error if you try to append the one XML object to the other." Also using jQuery might save you a lot oh trouble as suggested earlier by webarto...

Answer (score 0):

This is too late to answer but here's the solution that should solve this problem.

I had a similar problem this week. Change the

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gradovi.php?selected=" + x.value, true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "gradovi.php?selected=" + x.value, true);
```

This solved my problem.
Check here:
[This PHP script doesn't work in Internet explorer and Microsoft Edge but works in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847535/this-php-script-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer-and-microsoft-edge-but-works-i)